# why I have set ~/.bashrc but it doesn't work?

Tags: linux

[image: I have set the ~/.bashrc file and reboot but it's useless.]

I want to change PS1 variable and I have set ~/.bashrc and /etc/skel/.bashrc

Comment: did you reload the .bashrc and/or restart your shell? simply changing the rc file won't affect any currently running shells.

Comment: I have rebooted the system

Comment: I have only root account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in /etc/skel/ are copied to the homes of new users when you create them, adding or modifying files there do not affect the existing users.

In the login shells bash reads its configuration from ~/.profile, in other interactive shells (like the ones you open in virtual terminals in X11) the configuration is read from ~/.bashrc.

So I guess you are using bash from regular terminal, therefore if you want bash to load your configuration you should edit ~/.profile.

Comment: I don't have ~/.profile this file so I created it.But which is the system-wide file that controls the regular bash environment?@Fernando

Comment: For the login shells /etc/profile (in Debian based systems you can also create a script in /etc/profile.d to have a modular configuration). For interactive shells in virtual terminals you have /etc/bash.bashrc.